# Changing Color of a column based on other column in put

Tags: excel, excel-formula, colors, conditional-formatting, fill

I have a table that has Color and Progress Interval Columns, I wanted to change the cell color in Progress Interval Column based on cell in Color Column. Example if Cell D2 says Green, E2 will be filled with Green.
[Snap Shot From Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l4LMh.png)

[image]

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for conditional formatting. What have you tried so far?

Comment: try this: Conditional formatting > New rule > "use a formula..." > =D2="Green"   etc

Comment: Welcome to SO! You may want to reformat a bit your question, including a title for the image.

Comment: I tried conditional formatting based on column D applies to column E. I used this formula "=($D$2:$D$12="Green")" and it turn all column E to green.

Comment: In cell E2 use **=D2="Green"**

Answer (score 0):

## Conditional Formatting

If `Progress Interval` is in column `E`, select the range from `E2` to the last cell e.g. `E20` and go to `Format >> Conditional Formatting`
choose `Formula is` and copy/paste the following formula:

```
=D2="Green"
```

Now click `Format` and click on the `Patterns` tab and choose the green color you need and change anything else (`Font, Border`). When done click OK.

Now you can click Add to add another condition and do the same for Yellow. When finished click OK.

If you want to exclude cells that contain no data use:

```
=AND(E2<>"",D2="Green")
```

Now only cells in the `E` column containing data will be hightlighted.

Comment: But this way I have to repeat this for each cell in Column E.

Comment: @Ahmed Çetiner: No, you just copy E2 and pastespecial formatting down or you select e,g, E2:E20 and then choose conditional formatting and then write the formula. Just like you did it the first time and don't use =$D$2:$D$12="Green", but use =D2="Green"